# TreeSet search taking long time ,puzzle: to find lucky numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, dynamic, puzzle

It actually is problem to find lucky number - those numbers whose sum of digits and sum of square of digits are prime. I have implemented [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Now to optimize it further I commented my getDigitSum method, that I suppose was heavy and replaced with two hard-coded value , but it is still taking minutes to solve one test case. [Here is a reference to actual problem asked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/puzzle-sum-of-the-digits-is-prime-or-not)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Solution {

private static int[] getDigitSum(long num) {

    long sum = 0;
    long squareSum = 0;
    for (long tempNum = num; tempNum > 0; tempNum = tempNum / 10) {
        if (tempNum < 0) {
            sum = sum + tempNum;
            squareSum = squareSum + (tempNum * tempNum);
        } else {
            long temp = tempNum % 10;
            sum = sum + temp;
            squareSum = squareSum + (temp * temp);

        }
    }
    int[] twosums = new int[2];
    twosums[0] = Integer.parseInt(sum+"");
    twosums[1] = Integer.parseInt(squareSum+"");
    // System.out.println("sum Of digits: " + twoDoubles[0]);
    // System.out.println("squareSum Of digits: " + twoDoubles[1]);
    return twosums;
}

public static Set<Integer> getPrimeSet(int maxValue) {
    boolean[] primeArray = new boolean[maxValue + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i < primeArray.length; i++) {
        primeArray[i] = true;
    }
    Set<Integer> primeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i < maxValue; i++) {
        if (primeArray[i]) {
            primeSet.add(i);
            markMutiplesAsComposite(primeArray, i);
        }
    }

    return primeSet;
}

public static void markMutiplesAsComposite(boolean[] primeArray, int value) {
    for (int i = 2; i*value < primeArray.length; i++) {
        primeArray[i * value] = false;

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    // getDigitSum(80001001000l);
    //System.out.println(getPrimeSet(1600));
    Set set = getPrimeSet(1600);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int totalCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for (int cases = 0; cases < totalCases; cases++) {
        String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
        long startRange = Long.parseLong(str[0]);
        long endRange = Long.parseLong(str[1]);
        int luckyCount = 0;
        for (long num = startRange; num <= endRange; num++) {
            int[] longArray = getDigitSum(num); \\this method was commented for testing purpose and was replaced with any two hardcoded values
            if(set.contains(longArray[0]) && set.contains(longArray[1])){
                luckyCount++;
            }


        }
        System.out.println(luckyCount);
    }

}
}
```

what I should use to cache the result so that it takes lesser amount of time to search, currently it takes huge no. of minutes to complete 10000 test cases with range 1 99999999999999(18 times 9 -the worst case) , even  thought the search values have been hard-coded for testing purpose( 1600, 1501 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different algorithm. Caching is not your problem.

If the range is large - and you can bet some will be - even a loop doing almost nothing would take a very long time. The end of the range is constrained to be no more than 10<sup>18</sup>, if I understand correctly. Suppose the start of the range is half that. Then you'd iterate over 5*10<sup>17</sup> numbers. Say you have a 2.5 GHz CPU, so you have 2.5*10<sup>9</sup> clock cycles per second. If each iteration took one cycle, that'd be 2*10<sup>8</sup> CPU-seconds. A year has about 3.1*10<sup>7</sup> seconds, so the loop would take roughly six and a half years.

Attack the problem from the other side. The sum of the squares of the digits can be at most 18*9<sup>2</sup>, that's 1458, a rather small number. The sum of the digits itself can be at most `18*9 = 162`.

For the primes less than 162, find out all possible decompositions as the sum of at most 18 digits (ignoring 0). Discard those decompositions for which the sum of the squares is not prime. Not too many combinations are left. Then find out how many numbers within the specified range you can construct using each of the possible decompositions (filling with zeros if required).

Comment: @Deniel I tried your approch but again finding combinations for a number like 162 will take very long to compute ...

Comment: Hmm, the largest prime below 162 is 157. You need 18 digits for that, at least 13 of which must be 9. So that gives `13*9 + 5*8`, sum of squares of digits 1373, prime, keep; `14*9 + 3*8 + 1*7`, sum of squares 1375, discard; `15*9 + 2*8 + 1*6`, squares 1379 = 7*197, discard; `15*9 + 1*8 + 2*7`, squares 1377 = 3^4*17, discard; `16*9 + 1*8 + 1*5`, squares 1385, discard; `16*9 + 1*7 + 1*6`, squares 1381, keep; `17*9 + 1*4`, squares 1393 = 7*199, discard. So you have two combinations, `13*9 + 5*8` and `16*9 + 1*7 + 1*6`. From the first set of digits, you can make 8568 numbers, from the second 306.

Comment: That's a matter of microseconds to check. You'll have far more possibilities for numbers in the middle of the range, say 50-100, but if you handle them in the right way (I'm not going to completely spoil the puzzle by telling you exactly how), it should still be fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are few places in this implementation that can be improved. In order to to start attacking the issues i made few changes first to get an idea of the main problems:
made the total start cases be the value 1 and set the range to be a billion (1,000,000,000) to have a large amount of iterations.  also I use the method "getDigitSum" but commented out the code that actually makes the sum of digits to see how the rest runs: following are the methods that were modified for an initial test run:

```
private static int[] getDigitSum(long num) {

    long sum = 0;
    long squareSum = 0;
//    for (long tempNum = num; tempNum > 0; tempNum = tempNum / 10) {
//        if (tempNum < 0) {
//            sum = sum + tempNum;
//            squareSum = squareSum + (tempNum * tempNum);
//        } else {
//            long temp = tempNum % 10;
//            sum = sum + temp;
//            squareSum = squareSum + (temp * temp);
//
//        }
//    }
    int[] twosums = new int[2];
    twosums[0] = Integer.parseInt(sum+"");
    twosums[1] = Integer.parseInt(squareSum+"");
    // System.out.println("sum Of digits: " + twoDoubles[0]);
    // System.out.println("squareSum Of digits: " + twoDoubles[1]);
    return twosums;
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    // getDigitSum(80001001000l);
    //System.out.println(getPrimeSet(1600));
    Set set = getPrimeSet(1600);
    //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int totalCases = 1;
    for (int cases = 0; cases < totalCases; cases++) {
        //String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
        long startRange = Long.parseLong("1");
        long endRange = Long.parseLong("1000000000");
        int luckyCount = 0;
        for (long num = startRange; num <= endRange; num++) {
            int[] longArray = getDigitSum(num); //this method was commented for testing purpose and was replaced with any two hardcoded values
            if(set.contains(longArray[0]) && set.contains(longArray[1])){
                luckyCount++;
            }


        }
        System.out.println(luckyCount);
    }

}
```

**Running the code takes 5 minutes 8 seconds.**
now we can start optimizing it step by step. I will now mention the various points in the implementation that can be optimized.

***1- in the method getDigitSum(long num)***

```
int[] twosums = new int[2];
twosums[0] = Integer.parseInt(sum+"");
twosums[1] = Integer.parseInt(squareSum+"");
```

the above is not good. on every call to this method, two String objects are created , e.g. (sum+"") , before they are parsed into an int. considering the method is called billion times in my test, that produces two billion String object creation operations. since you know that the value is an int (according to the math in there and based on the links you provided), it would be enough to use casting:

```
twosums[0] = (int)sum;
twosums[1] = (int)squareSum;
```

**2- In the "Main" method, you have the following**

```
for (long num = startRange; num <= endRange; num++) {
            int[] longArray = getDigitSum(num); \\this method was commented for testing purpose and was replaced with any two hardcoded values
            if(set.contains(longArray[0]) && set.contains(longArray[1])){
                luckyCount++;
            }
   }
```

here  there are few issues:

**a- set.contains(longArray[0])** will create an  Integer object (with autoboxing) because contains method requires an object. this is a big waste and is not necessary. in our example, billion Integer objects will be created. Also, usage of set, whether it is a treeset or hash set is not the best for our case.

what you are trying to do is to get a set that contains the prime numbers in the range 1 .. 1600. this way, to check if a number in the range is prime, you check if it is contained in the set. This is not good as there are billions of calls to the set contains method. instead, your boolean array that you made when filling the set can be used: to find if the number 1500 is prime, simply access the index 1500 in the array. this is much faster solution. since its only 1600 elements (1600 is greater than  max sum of sqaures of digits of your worst case), the wasted memory for the false locations is not an issue compared to the gain in speed.

**b- int[] longArray = getDigitSum(num);**
    an int array is being allocated and returned. that will happen billion times. in our case, we can define it once outside the loop and send it to the method where it gets filled. on billion iterations, this saved 7 seconds, not a big change by itslef. but if the test cases are repeated 1000 times as you plan, that is 7000 second.

therefore, after modifying the code to implement all of the above, here is what you will have:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Solution {

private static void getDigitSum(long num,int[] arr) {

    long sum = 0;
    long squareSum = 0;
//    for (long tempNum = num; tempNum > 0; tempNum = tempNum / 10) {
//        if (tempNum < 0) {
//            sum = sum + tempNum;
//            squareSum = squareSum + (tempNum * tempNum);
//        } else {
//            long temp = tempNum % 10;
//            sum = sum + temp;
//            squareSum = squareSum + (temp * temp);
//
//        }
//    }
    arr[0] = (int)sum;
    arr[1] = (int)squareSum;
    // System.out.println("sum Of digits: " + twoDoubles[0]);
    // System.out.println("squareSum Of digits: " + twoDoubles[1]);

}

public static boolean[] getPrimeSet(int maxValue) {
    boolean[] primeArray = new boolean[maxValue + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i < primeArray.length; i++) {
        primeArray[i] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < maxValue; i++) {
        if (primeArray[i]) {
            markMutiplesAsComposite(primeArray, i);
        }
    }

    return primeArray;
}

public static void markMutiplesAsComposite(boolean[] primeArray, int value) {
    for (int i = 2; i*value < primeArray.length; i++) {
        primeArray[i * value] = false;

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    // getDigitSum(80001001000l);
    //System.out.println(getPrimeSet(1600));
    boolean[] primeArray = getPrimeSet(1600);
    //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int totalCases = 1;
    for (int cases = 0; cases < totalCases; cases++) {
        //String[] str = br.readLine().split(" ");
        long startRange = Long.parseLong("1");
        long endRange = Long.parseLong("1000000000");
        int luckyCount = 0;
        int[] longArray=new int[2];
        for (long num = startRange; num <= endRange; num++) {
            getDigitSum(num,longArray); //this method was commented for testing purpose and was replaced with any two hardcoded values
            if(primeArray[longArray[0]] && primeArray[longArray[1]]){
                luckyCount++;
            }


        }
        System.out.println(luckyCount);
    }

}
}
```

**Running the code takes 4 seconds.**

the billion iterations cost 4 seconds instead of 5 minutes 8 seconds, that is an improvement. the only issue left is the actual calculation of the sum of digits and sum of squares of digits. that code i commented out (as you can see in the code i posted). if you uncomment it, the runtime will take 6-7 minutes. and here, there is nothing to improve except if you find some mathematical way to have incremental calculation based on previous results.